# SQL query - Difference between the values from two rows and two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am struggling to get this working, using T-SQL Query (SQL SERVER 2008) for the following problem:

```
Ky  ProductID  Start #  End #    Diff
1     100        10      12        0
2     100        14      20        2 (14 - 12)
3     100        21      25        1 (21 - 20)
4     100        30      33        5 (30 - 25) 
1     110        6       16        0
2     110        20      21        4 (20 - 16)
3     110        22      38        1 (22 - 21)
```

as you can see I need the difference between values in two different rows and two columns.

I tried

```
with t1 
( select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION by ProductID ORDER BY ProductID, Start# ) as KY
       , productid
       , start#
       , end# 
  from mytable)
```

and

```
select DATEDIFF(ss, T2.complete_dm, T1.start_dm)
   , <Keeping it simple not including all the columns which I selected..>  
FROM T1 as T2 
RIGHT OUTER JOIN T1 on T2.Ky + 1  = T1.KY  
             and T1.ProductID = T2.ProductID
```

The problem with the above query is when the productID  changes from 100 to 110 still it calculates the difference.

Any help in modifying the query or any simpler solution much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to calculate the difference just for ProductID 100. I tried same query it works for me. The Table you showed, is that your desired output? --> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e4f23/6

Comment: It should be for 110 as well. Infact the desied output is for many columns, just didn't include as you can see the difference is for the datetime but just to keep it simple I had given the #. I saw the query, seems to be same as I tried I think I must have missed something..That's the desired result I want.

Answer (score 2):

You can try below code for the required result :

```
select ky,Start,[End],(select  [end]  from table1 tt where (tt.ky)=(t.ky-1) and tt.ProductID=t.ProductID) [End_Prev_Row],
       case ky when 1 then 0
       else (t.start -(select  [end]  from table1 tt where (tt.ky)=(t.ky-1) and tt.ProductID=t.ProductID)) 
       end as Diff      
from table1 t
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/347bb/7)**

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that. It should give you the difference you want. I'm getting the first row for each product in the first part and then recursively build up by using the next `Ky`.

```
with t1 
as
( 
    select  ProductID, Ky, 0 as Difference, [End#]
    from mytable where ky = 1

    union all
    select m.ProductID, m.Ky, m.[Start#] - t1.[End#] as Difference, m.[End#]
    from mytable m
    inner join t1 on m.ProductID = t1.ProductID and m.Ky = t1.Ky + 1
)

select Ky, ProductID, Difference from t1
order by ProductID, Ky
```

Answer (score 0):

As Anup has mentioned, your query seems to be working fine, I just *removed* **DateDiff** to calculate the difference, as I assume columns are not of DATE datatype from your example, I guess that was the issue, please find below the modified query

```
with t1  
as  
( select ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION by ProductID ORDER BY ProductID ) as KY  
   , productid  
   , st  
   , ed  
from YourTable)  

select T1.ProductID, t1.ST,t1.ED, ISNULL(T1.st - T2.ed,0) as Diff  
FROM T1 as T2  
RIGHT OUTER JOIN T1 on T2.KY+1 = T1.KY  
         and T1.ProductID = T2.ProductID
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION by rc.ContractID ORDER BY rc.ID) AS ROWID,rc.ID,rc2.ID,rc.ContractID,rc2.ContractID,rc.ToDate,rc2.FromDate
FROM tbl_RenewContracts rc
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_RenewContracts rc2
ON rc2.ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM tbl_RenewContracts rcs WHERE rcs.ID < rc.ID AND rcs.ContractID = rc.ContractID) 
ORDER BY rc.ContractID
```

Replace your table name and columns and add calculated column to get the `DATEDIFF`.